# Count number of days based on custom time unit

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I have a class with number and timeUnit

```
public static class Time {
    private int number;
    private Unit unit;
}
```

TimeUnit is an enum

```
public enum Unit {
    days,
    months,
    years;
}
```

So the possible values of Time are

```
[0-Integer.MAX] DAYS
[0-Integer.MAX] MONTHS
[0-Integer.MAX] YEARS
```

I want to minus the Time from Today's date but now sure how I can achieve it.

Here is an example,

> if TimePeriod is 30 DAYS, then resultedDate = Instant.now() - 30 DAYS.
>
> if TimePeriod is 15 MONTHS, then resultedDate = Instant.now() - 450
>   DAYS
>
> if TimePeriod is 2 YEARS, then resultedDate = Instant.now() - 730 DAYS

Comment: So you want to count 12 months as 360 days but a year as 365 days, both regardless of leap years? Also have you considered using the `Period` class?

Comment: This doesn't seem very accurate and are you obliged to use `Instant` ? Why not `LocalDate` ?

Comment: TimePeriod is a parameter object of a REST API, where I am expecting the input in the form of `an int and a timeUnit`. Not sure if I can modify that. I want a local date to filter out the results.

Comment: We have classes to do all this, found in the *java.time* classes. Seems quite silly to reinvent this functionality.

Comment: @OleV.V. I have used the period class for this and it also got me the correct result. However, from your comment, I realized that I need to consider 12 months not as 360 days and also calculate leap years. Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realized that I need to consider 12 months not as 360 days and also
>   calculate leap years. Any ideas for that?

First you need to decide on a time zone for that. Why? Say you were running this code at (UTC) 2019-02-28T23:00:00Z and you want to subtract 1 month. At this point in time it’s February 28 in Mexico City, so the result should fall on January 28. By contrast in Shanghai it’s already March 1, so the result should fall on February 1. The difference is 3 days (72 hours).

Once you’ve decided on a time zone, it’s easiest to use `ZonedDateTime`. You can always convert to `Instant` after subtracting, that’s straightforward too.

For example:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Ashkhabad");
    Map<Unit, ChronoUnit> units = Map.of(Unit.days, ChronoUnit.DAYS,
            Unit.months, ChronoUnit.MONTHS, Unit.years, ChronoUnit.YEARS);

    Time timeToSubtract = new Time(15, Unit.months);

    Instant result = ZonedDateTime.now(zone)
            .minus(timeToSubtract.getNumber(), units.get(timeToSubtract.getUnit()))
            .toInstant();
    System.out.println("15 months ago was " + result);
```

When running just now (2019-05-08T07:06:45Z) I got this output:

> 15 months ago was 2018-02-08T07:06:45.353746Z

The `ZonedDateTime.minus` method that I am using understands `ChronoUnit` but of course not your `Unit` enum, so since you get the latter, we need to translate (or your enum would have to implement `TemporalUnit`,  but that would be overkill). I am using a map for the translation. I am initializing the map the Java 9 way. If you are still on Java 8, I trust you to fill it some other way.

In my code I have assumed that your `Time` class has usual constructor and getters.

`ZonedDateTime` also takes into account that a day is not always 24 hours. For example, when in spring summer time (DST) begins and the clocks are turned forward, the day is only 23 hours. And then 25 hours the day the clocks are turned back in the fall.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
public enum TimeUnit {
    DAYS(1),
    MONTHS(30),
    YEARS(365);

    private final int days;

    private TimeUnit(int days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public <R extends Temporal> R addTo(R temporal, long amount) {
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.addTo(temporal, Math.multiplyExact(amount, this.days));
    }
}
```

<sup>*) Using [`multiplyExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-long-long-) to fail in case of numeric overflow.</sup>

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Instant.now());
System.out.println(TimeUnit.DAYS.addTo(Instant.now(), -30));
System.out.println(TimeUnit.MONTHS.addTo(Instant.now(), -15));
System.out.println(TimeUnit.YEARS.addTo(Instant.now(), -2));
```

*Sample output*

```
2019-05-06T21:04:50.781231200Z
2019-04-06T21:04:50.781231200Z
2018-02-10T21:04:50.781231200Z
2017-05-06T21:04:50.781231200Z
```

*Sample output of you replace `Instant` with `LocalDate`*

```
2019-05-06
2019-04-06
2018-02-10
2017-05-06
```

Comment: This is a good one, but in my case, I really don't want to touch the enum. It exists for a different purpose and can't really add any logic to it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a method to your `TimePeriod` class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class TimePeriod implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @PositiveOrZero
    private int number;
    @NonNull
    private TimeUnit timeUnit;

    public Instant getSubstractedDate() {
        int totalDays = number;
        switch (timeUnit) {
            case MONTHS: totalDays*=30; break;
            case YEARS: totalDays*=365; break;
        }
        return Instant.now().minus(number, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    }
}
```

Using `java.time.LocalDate` would be even better since you have the `LocalDate#minusDays` method to use. And it probably also makes more sense in our case. Using an `Instant` for `DAYS` as minimum granularity is not really ideal.

Comment: Yes! This is what I needed. Thanks a lot! I tried and works in this case. I get your point of using LocalDate. But I need an instant for further processing.

Comment: Also be aware that adding a day to an `Instant` always means adding 24 hours even though in your user's time zone a day may sometimes be for example 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: @OleV.V. Good point indeed. One of the other cons of working with `Instant`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. Thanks, @Yasin Hajaj & @OleV.V for giving the right answers. But Olev V.V's answer solved the problem more accurately.

Added `ChronoUnit` to `Unit` enum

```
public enum Unit {
    days(ChronoUnit.DAYS),
    months(ChronoUnit.MONTHS),
    years(ChronoUnit.YEARS);

    private final ChronoUnit chronoUnit;

    Unit(final ChronoUnit chronoUnit) {
        this.chronoUnit = chronoUnit;
    }

    public ChronoUnit toChronoUnit() {
        return chronoUnit;
    }
}
```

And the place to calculate the dates, I am calling like this

```
Time timeToSubtract = new Time(15, Unit.months);

Instant result = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
        .minus(timeToSubtract.getNumber(), units.get(timeToSubtract.getUnit()))
        .toInstant();

System.out.println("15 months ago was " + result);
```

This returns the subtracted period, which includes the leap years and months with 30/31 days.